# MySQL only select when value (float) has changed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table of data:
*Table name entity_values*

| date_time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-09-02 05:05:00 | 20 |
| 2017-09-02 05:10:00 | 20 |
| 2017-09-02 05:15:00 | 21 |
| 2017-09-02 05:20:00 | 21 |
| 2017-09-02 05:25:00 | 21 |
| 2017-09-02 05:30:00 | 22 |

I currently only want to see the changes so I build the following query:

```
SELECT  date_time AS 'time',  
 value - LAG(value) over (order by date_time) as 'Kwh01-Energy (kWh)' 
FROM entity_values;
```

This returns the following:

| date_time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-09-02 05:00:00 | 0 |
| 2017-09-02 05:05:00 | 0 |
| 2017-09-02 05:10:00 | 1 |
| 2017-09-02 05:15:00 | 0 |
| 2017-09-02 05:20:00 | 0 |
| 2017-09-02 05:25:00 | 1 |

Since Window Functions *aren't allowed* in the WHERE clause like:

```
SELECT  date_time AS 'time',  
 value - LAG(value) over (order by date_time) as 'Kwh01-Energy (kWh)' 
FROM entity_values 
WHERE (value - LAG(value) over (order by date_time)) > 0;
```

> Error Code: 3593. You cannot use the window function 'lag' in this context.'

**Question**: How do I filter out the 0 values and only get the "changed" values?
Desired result:

| date_time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-09-02 05:10:00 | 1 |
| 2017-09-02 05:25:00 | 1 |

Comment: PS: I also don't know how to fix the tables I made for this post

Comment: Just wrap your select in an  outer query - `select t.* from (<your query>)  t where value = 1`

Comment: To fix the formatting of tables, don't indent them by 4 characters. Text indented 4 characters is treated "as is," and this is typically use for formatting code.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @Andrew

```
SELECT t.* from (
SELECT 
date_time,
value - LAG(value) over (order by date_time) as changed_value
FROM entity_values 
) as t 
WHERE changed_value > 0
```